# Python How to merge in a list of dicts content from another list of dicts dynamically

Tags: python

I'm not very familiar with Python and I don't really know how to get the desired result, I've spent some time checking previous questions and answers but nothing.

Let's say I have two lists of dicts:

List A:

```
[{'g_type': 2, 'h_loss': 1, 'record_id': 15517, 'Start': 20763313}, {'g_type': 2, 'h_loss': 1, 'record_id': 15517, 'Start': 20763314}]
```

List B:

```
[{'in_data': '', 'espn': 'GJB2:NM_004004.5:exon2:c.C408A:p.Y136X', 's_id': 'CBK0944'}, {'in_data': '', 'espn': 'GJB2:NM_004004.5:exon2:c.G134A:p.G45E','s_id': 'CBK0945'}]
```

Let's assume that List A[0] corresponds to List B[0] etc.

How can I do something like this for each dict in the lists?:

```
in_data = in_data + s_id + '(' + g_type + ', ' + h_loss + ')'
```

List B with the desired result:

```
[{'in_data': 'CBK0944(2, 1)', 'espn': 'GJB2:NM_004004.5:exon2:c.C408A:p.Y136X', 's_id': 'CBK0944'}, {'in_data': 'CBK0945(2, 1)', 'espn': 'GJB2:NM_004004.5:exon2:c.G134A:p.G45E','s_id': 'CBK0945'}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over `ListA` and `ListB` at the same time and [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) to format the strings in your required format.

```
for a, b in zip(ListA, ListB):
    b["in_data"] = f'{b["in_data"]}{b["s_id"]}({a["g_type"]}, {a["h_loss"]})'
```

Answer (score 3):

Code:

```
List_A = [{'g_type': 2, 'h_loss': 1, 'record_id': 15517, 'Start': 20763313}, {'g_type': 2, 'h_loss': 1, 'record_id': 15517, 'Start': 20763314}]

List_B = [{'in_data': '', 'espn': 'GJB2:NM_004004.5:exon2:c.C408A:p.Y136X', 's_id': 'CBK0944'}, {'in_data': '', 'espn': 'GJB2:NM_004004.5:exon2:c.G134A:p.G45E','s_id': 'CBK0945'}]


for idx, item in enumerate(List_B):
    item['in_data'] += '{0}({1}, {2})'.format(item['s_id'],List_A[idx]['g_type'], List_A[idx]['h_loss'])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to keep both list in its original state for reference, you can recreate a new one with list comprehension below:

```
li_a = [{'g_type': 2, 'h_loss': 1, 'record_id': 15517, 'Start': 20763313}, {'g_type': 2, 'h_loss': 1, 'record_id': 15517, 'Start': 20763314}]
li_b = [{'in_data': '', 'espn': 'GJB2:NM_004004.5:exon2:c.C408A:p.Y136X', 's_id': 'CBK0944'}, {'in_data': '', 'espn': 'GJB2:NM_004004.5:exon2:c.G134A:p.G45E','s_id': 'CBK0945'}]

merge = [{'in_data': '{}{}({},{})'.format(b['in_data'], b['s_id'], a['g_type'], a['h_loss']),
          'espn':b['espn'],
          's_id':b['s_id']
         } for a,b in zip(li_a,li_b)]
merge

>> [{'in_data': 'CBK0944(2,1)',
  'espn': 'GJB2:NM_004004.5:exon2:c.C408A:p.Y136X',
  's_id': 'CBK0944'},
 {'in_data': 'CBK0945(2,1)',
  'espn': 'GJB2:NM_004004.5:exon2:c.G134A:p.G45E',
  's_id': 'CBK0945'}]
```